# Ipad 2 screen replacement, small cut in LCD

Tags: ipad, screen, damage

I'm working on replacing the digitizer on my ipad 2.  In the process, I put a small cut in the bottom of the LCD (I think there is even a little liquid leaking out).  I'm certain that area of the LCD will no longer function, but what effect will it have on the rest of the screen?  Will most of the screen work or does that little cut ruin the whole screen?  The cut is along the bottom edge of the screen.

Comment: what liquid are you talking about ?